# Emulating ng-model two way data binding in VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm used to using the AngularJS framework and I came across an obstacle upon using VanillaJS that seems pretty simple, but when I went online I only found out of date practices.

Firstly, I need to be able to essentially have a `<textarea>` element and propagate its changes immediately to JS to HTML. For example (in JS psuedocode):

```
 <textarea id="#editor" when-changed="foo(newValue)"></textarea>
 <p id="#parsedEditor"></p>

 function foo(newValue) {
     document.getElementByID("#parsedEditor") = bar(newValue);
 }

 function bar(text) {
     return text.replace(" ", "x");
  }
```

What I want is whenever the value of `textarea` is changed, it gets passed through some filter and then it gets rendered to the front-end.

In this case, whenever the value of `#editor` is changed, its new value is sent to a callback function `foo` and it gets parsed using the `bar` filter and the `#parsedEditor` gets updated with the new value. In AngularJS it would basically be (disregarding exact syntax and best practices):

```
 <textarea ng-model="text"></textarea>
 <p ng-bind-html="parsedText"></p>

 function controller($scope) {
     $scope.$watch('text', function(newValue, oldValue) {
          $scope.parsedText = newValue.replace(" ", "x");
     }
 }
```

I searched online for the ways to do this, and found `Object.observe()` which is only a new proposed method and `.watch()` which was not recommended on MDN. Furthermore `onchange` attribute only invokes the callback function after the `textarea` element is de-selected and I would like to propagate it whenever the value changes not when it gets de-selected.

I feel like there must be an easier way to do this in JS that I am missing?

Comment: can you use the "input" event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Comment: @mcgraphix, isn't that a HTML5 specification?

Comment: Yes. It is pretty well supported in the most current browsers. IE 9 or earlier would not work completely though. See http://caniuse.com/#search=input

Comment: Looking into this I think `input` or `Mutation` is the best way, thanks for your suggestion and feel free to post an answer

Comment: You can actually borrow from Angular, it has got fairly complex battle-proven way to watch for input changes. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.5/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1108

Comment: I wouldn't suggest the Mutation events. They are deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code based on my comment above:

```
<textarea id="#editor" oninput="foo(event.currentTarget.value)"></textarea>
<p id="#parsedEditor"></p>
```

I'm assuming that your intent was to replace all spaces with an x. If so, you would probably want a regular expression:

```
function foo(newValue) {
   document.getElementById("#parsedEditor").innerText = bar(newValue);
}

function bar(text) {
   return text.replace(/\s/gi, "x");
}
```

You would need to test in all the browsers you are targeting and remember that the HTML5 apis don't always work as expected in IE9: http://caniuse.com/#search=input

Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/mcgraphix/71evt900/